# Which Command to Use in CakePHP 2.X similar to Dispatcher::baseUrl()?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I  need this because to use in my Ajax Request, in the url attribute.
like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post', /
    url: 'categories/add',  //Dispatcher::baseUrl()
    data: params, 
});
```

But, in cake2, it has been removed

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `Dispatcher::baseUrl` for such purposes, I'd always go with something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: <?php echo json_encode($this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'add'))); ?>,
    data: params, 
});
```

Comment: does not work:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method View::url() in /var/www/teste/View/Categories/index.ctp on line 122

Comment: Then try `Router::url` instead.

Answer (score 0):

use this one $this->webroot

its already have previous version and on 2.0 is available